# Is it possible to get element id by attribute's value and set an attribute to the parentNode

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get an element by a href value, and get the parentNode of this element, and finally set the parentNode an attribute.

Here is a code explaining what I'm trying to do:

```
        var uri = "index.html"; //just for the example
        var elementA = document.querySelector("." + uri);
        var elementLi = elementA.parentNode;
        elementLi.setAttribute("class", "current-menu-item");
```

The problem that it's saying:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null

I read few other question similar to mine but none of them solved it.
As far as I understood the `querySelector` isn't giving all the features you can do on an element because this method returns a static list.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to make here?

**If my question wasn't clear, please comment and let me know I will try to improve the question**

Comment: Have you looked at the Docs?

Comment: @CallumLinington Yes I did. See I wrote that as far as I understood querySelectorAll doesn't working with what I'm trying to do because it's returns a static list.

Comment: Bergi seems to beg to differ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute nodes are deprecated, just use the  [`setAttribute` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute):

```
elementLi.setAttribute("class", "current-menu-item");
```

However, your actual problem is that `elementLi` is `undefined`, as `elementA` is not an element node - [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a collection of nodes that you need to loop over!

```
var uri = "index.html"; //just for the example
var elementsA = document.querySelectorAll("a[href="+JSON.stringify(uri)+"]");
for (var i=0; i<elementsA.length; i++) {
    var elementLi = elementsA[i].parentNode;
    elementLi.setAttribute("class", "current-menu-item");
}
```

If you use `querySelector` to get a single element only, it still might be `null`, so better check that:

```
var uri = "index.html"; //just for the example
var elementA = document.querySelector("a[href="+JSON.stringify(uri)+"]");
if (elementA) {
    var elementLi = elementA.parentNode;
    elementLi.setAttribute("class", "current-menu-item");
}
```

Comment: First, thank you for trying to help me, second I updated the question. You can see the script has changed and the error message too. I'm gonna try your method too and I will let you know if it works.

Comment: If `querySelector` returned `null`, then there is no element that matches your selector. Indeed, you've constructed a class selector, so it would elements that had an attribute like `class="index html"`. See my answer on how to "*get an element by a href value*"

Comment: working on it, seems you just found my problem. I will update you soon if it is the problem, thanks

Comment: Offered an edit to the answer, just optimize it as best as you can and I will be able to accept the answer. Thanks!